# Trying to understand require.js usage in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I've been trying a few suggested way to load my own js into a custom Magento theme and have not been successful.

In requirejs-config.js in root of my custom theme directory, I have this:

```
  var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
          "customBootstrap": "js/bootstrap.min",
          "customLocal":     "js/local"
        }
    },
  shim: {
      "customLocal": {
          deps: [
              "customBootstrap"
          ]
      },
      "customBootstrap": {
          deps: [
              "jquery"
          ]
      }
  },
};
```

The js files are in `[theme]/web/js/bootstrap.min.js` and `[theme]/web/js/local.js`

What needs to change so it loads correctly in the order of:
jquery
-> customBootstrap
-> custom Local

The local.js seems to be loading, but bootstrap.min.js is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep below format in requirejs-config.js file,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            "customBootstrap": "js/bootstrap.min",
            "customLocal":     "js/local"
        },   
    shim: {
        'customBootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        "customLocal": {
          deps: ['customBootstrap']
       },
    }
};
```

**Remove var folder from root.
Remove pub/static folder content and run command**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy